# Can I stop one instance's listener without affecting other instances on the same server

Tags: oracle, listener

I have many instances on one Oracle server running 11GR2.  I have to fix an issue on one instance.  According to Oracle support, I need to shutdown the database and its listener.

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

I can also use `svcctl` to start and stop a listener on the server as well:

```
srvctl stop listener -n node_name
```

I notice that the lsnrctl and srvctl are all based on the server/host/node level.  Can I stop one instance's listener without affecting other instances on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a

> lsnrctl status

command, you'll see all of the instances you'd affect by shutting down the listener. Generally you're going to be running only one listener on a server, so you'd shut off network access to all of the databases it serves.

Answer (score 1):

I would not stop the listener in order to bounce one of the instances and adjust a parameter. 
The instance will automatically register with the listener when it comes back up.

On the other hand, if we are talking about an inter-process issue you might have to. More details needed.
Remember, already established sessions to your instances will not be affected by a listener outage.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick responses.  I have 4 instances on one server so I have to inform all users for 4 different applications for this listener outage.  Yes, I did mention in my email that only NEW client or applicaiton connections will be impacted.  I wish that Oracle will add a new feature that I can shutdown one instance listener at a time, so other instances would not be affected.